# SetPixelFormat returns 0, but no error is set?

Tags: opengl, vb6, wine

I'm running a VB6 app in WINE and the OpenGL portion of the program doesn't work.  It is using PFD_DRAW_TO_BITMAP.  PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW formats seem to work.

I've enumerated all the pixel formats (there are around 256) and a few of them match what I request.  ChoosePixelFormat seems to return a correct format (in this case pixelFormat 6), but when I pass this value into SetPixelFormat it returns 0.  I looked at the documentation and it says to check GetLastError() for more information, but when I call that, it returns 0 which formats to a blank error message.

Does anyone know anyway to figure out why SetPixelFormat would fail?  I've done some reading and it sounds like DRAW_TO_BITMAP has been implemented since like May 2009.

I know DRAW_TO_BITMAP is not hardware accelerated.  That is perfectly acceptable.  This app works fine in Windows, -- I just need to figure out why a supported pixel format doesn't seem to get recognized.

I'm running Ubuntu, most recent version of WINE in their package manager, -- on a Quadro if that matters (not sure if Wine attempts to use the underlying graphics card or if it virtualizes all the pixel formats for software rendering)

Comment: Have you tested it on a real Windows install to see if it's a Wine bug?

Comment: Yeah, it works on my Windows install.  Works on every install I've tried it on except 3.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why `SetPixelFormat` would be failing only on WINE, but it is in any case incorrect to call `GetLastError` manually from VB6 code. VB makes its own DLL calls behind the scenes. These will (generally) succeed, resetting the error code seen by `GetLastError` and making it useless from VB code.

Instead, VB calls `GetLastError` itself immediately after every user-initiated DLL call. It saves the value and makes it available as the property `Err.LastDllError`. Use that to find out the real error code.